# Adding a validation check to a form in a while loop php

Tags: php, forms, validation, while-loop

I have a form which displays like this:
Event Name : Drop down menu

I am trying to add a check that ensures that each event produced by the while loop has a student assigned to it - by selecting from the drop down menu.

I have attempted adding a check for this but its not making a difference - it loads form action page 'savecompetitors'.

I have got this for php so far:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'db/connect.php';
require_once 'db/checkuserloggedin.php';
include 'db/header.php';

echo $_SESSION['Username'] . ' logged in successfully';
echo '<h3> Entry form </h3>';

//Query to display all events                           
if ($event_result = $con->query("SELECT Name FROM event")) {

    echo "<form method =\"POST\" action=\"savecompetitors.php\">";
    echo '<table>';
    while ($row = $event_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $row['Name'] . ' ';
        echo '</td>';

        if ($student_result = $con->query("SELECT Student.Form, Teacher.Form, Forename, Surname, Student_ID " .
            "FROM student, teacher " .
            "WHERE Student.Form = Teacher.Form AND Teacher.Username = '" . $_SESSION['Username'] . "'")
        ) {

            if ($student_result->num_rows) {
                echo '<td>';
                echo "<select name ='" . $row['Name'] . "'>";

                while ($row1 = $student_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<option value="" style="display:none;"></option>';
                    echo "<option value ='" . $row1['Student_ID'] . "'>" . $row1['Forename'] . ' ' . $row1['Surname'] . "</option>";

                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        if (empty($_POST['Student_ID'])) {
                            $error = 'A student must be selected for every event';
                        }
                    }

                }

                echo "</select>";
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value ="Submit" >';
    echo '<input type="reset" value ="Reset">';
    echo '<span class="error"><?php echo $error;?></span>';
    echo '<span class="error"><?php echo $success;?></span>';
    echo "</form>";
} else {
    echo 'No student records available';
}
```

savecompetitors php:

```
<?php
require_once 'db/connect.php';
$error = '';
$success = '';

$event_result = $con->query("SELECT Event_ID, Name from event");
while ($row = $event_result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $eventname = str_replace(' ', '_', $row['Name']);
    print_r($row);

    $con->query("INSERT INTO competitors (Event_ID, Student_ID) VALUES (" . $row['Event_ID'] . ", " . $_POST[$eventname] . ")   ");
    $success = 'Entry form has been successfully saved and students are entered as competitors for their submitted events';
}
```

Comment: Consider splitting this code into discrete functions. Makes it easier to maintain and read. No one likes to read into seven levels of indentation. Also, interpolating superglobals into queries without sanitizing them makes you vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: @Gordon sorry about the indentation issues. this form only has drop down menus to select form, so no need for sql injection, any ideas on this validation check?

Comment: What kind of forms you have is irrelevant. What gets send to your server is what matters.

Comment: @Gordon but real escape string and strip slashes will fix this. also, how they can they inject input into a dropdown, i've misunderstood this concept

Comment: A better option than real escape string and strip slashes would be to use prepared statements. Your form can easily be tampered with. It lives on the client side and it's trivial to change it's option values with your browser's developer tools. Much more important though is that it doesn't need a form to send an http request with arbitrary values to your server, for instance with cURL. That's why you should treat all input to your scripts as potentially malicious